# Confluence DB Connection Setup

Tags: oracle, confluence

I was reading Atlassian's Confluence Setup guide for Oracle Database connections, but I get the impression that setting up this connectivity between Oracle and Confluence is something that can only be done at the installation of Confluence, not well afterwards.

I am trying to create this relationship between an already installed Confluence and Oracle. Can this be done?

Comment: See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migrating+to+Another+Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this document. It should help you out.

[Migrating to Another Database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migrating+to+Another+Database)

Answer (score 0):

I could find a simple database migration solution for confluence,
you should follow these steps:

1. backup your current data
2. shutdown confluence server
3. edit {confluence.home}/confluence.cfg.xml
   and change  these :
   complete
   install
   to :
   setupdbchoice-start
   custom
   and remove all hibernate related properties
4. copy your database connector jar file to server lib folder
5. copy exprted file to {confluence.home}/restore folder
6. start confluence server
7. continue database configuration wizard
8. follow restore wizard

Good Luck